# MVC: how can I sign up controller on View events (c#)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

It’s possible to:

1. Set up the event handlers in the Controller to capture View events.
2. Use event handlers in View and immediately call the Controller from it.

There are no problems with the second method, but how can the first be implemented? And what is the benefit of using it comparing to using the second method?

Comment: The event model is something we're missing in MVC still unfortunately, the only way to emulate this is via Javascript/jQuery which in turn calls the controller via an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - MVC is stateless (unless you use WebSockets) and it's impossible to keep relations between objects in runtime, when every request is like running new instance of a whole application.

Comment: I don't think I've got it. Could You please explain Your opinion or give some example?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54576/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-View-Controller-Ar

Comment: It's like having two separated applications in completely different environments (client browser - javascript and on the other side app server with .Net application). How whould you like to gain control over client process ?